# iOS Core Data lightweight migration in new version

Tags: core-data, migration

I have an app with multiple updates on the AppStore already, funny thing happened, I thought that the lightweight migration happens automatically, however, my recent discovery that I need to add the

```
NSDictionary *storeOptions = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES};
```

to my **persistentStoreCoordinator** shook my confidence when I realized I already have 5 core data models.

**The question is:** when I add the above line to the next version of the app, is it going to work for everyone when they update? Because right now everything that happens when they open the app .. is a fancy CRASH.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

It will work **if automatic lightweight migration is possible** for the migration you're trying to perform. Whether this will work depends on the differences between the model used for the existing data and the current version of the model. [Many common changes permit automatic lightweight migration](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH4-SW1) but not all. You'll need to review the docs on this kind of migration and decide whether it will work in your case.

If it doesn't work, there are other ways to handle it, for example by [creating a mapping file](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMappingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH5-SW1) to tell Core Data how to make changes that it can't infer automatically.

Comment: The changes I have made are only adding a handful of attributes

Comment: Well then maybe you could describe the crashes in detail, because there are usually lots of useful clues.